# Motion under gravitational forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, celestial-mechanics

In a system of particles, can a particle be considered to be attracted to the combined center of mass of the other particles if the Newton's universal law of gravitation is used (the inverse square law model)?

Comment: This actually works only for certain configurations. If it were true in general, N-body problems would be much easier than they are.

Answer (score 3):

It's not as simple as that.

Imagine two objects, both with mass $1$, one on the point $(-1,0,0)$, the other on the point $(1,0,0)$. Then imagine a third particle on the point $(x,0,0)$ for some $x\in[-1,1]$. If $x>0$, then the sum of all forces on the third particle is a force that points to the right, **not** to the center of mass.

Comment: Note that even if you take the center of mass of all _three_ particles, the direction of the force is still opposite to the direction to the center of mass.

Comment: This seems to be a very complex situation indeed.Possibly related :https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem